# Crear sistema de carpetas

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy intentando crear un programa en python que cree una estructura de carpetas, mi idea es que

Una ventana en TKinter que te pregunta como se tiene que llamar la carpeta
Crear en el escritorio el nombre de lo que hayas escrito y que dentro albergue una carpeta llamada totales dentro de "fecha segun el equipo + lo que se haya introducido en la ventana"

Cabe decir que aun soy muy novato en esto de la programacion, esto es lo que he conseguido hacer

```
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("TMS Folder Creator")
        #setting window size
        width=500
        height=200
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        GMessage_534=tk.Message(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GMessage_534["font"] = ft
        GMessage_534["fg"] = "#333333"
        GMessage_534["justify"] = "center"
        GMessage_534["text"] = "Escribe el nombre del evento "
        GMessage_534.place(x=140,y=20,width=200,height=53)

        GLineEdit_769=tk.Entry(root)
        GLineEdit_769["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_769["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_769["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_769["justify"] = "center"
        GLineEdit_769["text"] = ""
        GLineEdit_769.place(x=170,y=70,width=134,height=30)

        GButton_596=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_596["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_596["font"] = ft
        GButton_596["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_596["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_596["text"] = "OK"
        GButton_596.place(x=200,y=120,width=70,height=25)
        GButton_596["command"] = self.GButton_596_command

    def GButton_596_command(self):
        print("OK")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error el código?, o cual es el problema que tienes, adjunta eso a tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida y podamos colaborarte. ;)

Comment: No me muestra error, simplemente es que no tengo ni idea de como puedo convertir esa caja de texto en un input para que lo reconozca como titulo de la carpeta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario agregar tantas líneas de código innecesarias, según lo que usted quiere es crear carpetas mediante el valor o texto de un cuadro de entrada de texto, solo es usar una cadena o String `str` y cuando se cree la carpeta se usara la cadena de texto ingresada en el Entry.

La solución es la siguiente:

```
import os
import tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry('312x130')
root.geometry('+360+20')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Nueva carpeta...')
root.maxsize(312, 130)
root.minsize(312, 130)

labelTextInfo = tk.Label(root, text="Especifique el nombre de la carpeta que va a crear.", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8))
labelTextInfo.place(x=7, y=8)

labelTextInfo2 = tk.Label(root, text="Nombre de la carpeta o ubicación:", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8))
labelTextInfo2.place(x=7, y=38)

def EnableButton(*args): # Verificar si hay texto en el cuadro de entrada, si no el botón de Aceptar estará deshabilitado
    try:
        if editWidgetVar.get(): # Variable de texto del cuadro de entrada, verfica si hay texto o no
            btnOk.config(state='normal')
        else:
            btnOk.config(state='disabled')
    except:
        print('Excepción no importante, ignorarado...')                

editWidgetVar = tk.StringVar() # Variable de texto del cuadro de entrada
editWidgetVar.trace("w", EnableButton)
editWidget =ttk.Entry(root ,font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), width=34, textvariable=editWidgetVar)
editWidget.place(x=11,y=62, height=21)
editWidget.focus_set()

SearchFilePropertyDialogButtonsStyle = ttk.Style() 

SearchFilePropertyDialogButtonsStyle.configure('E.TButton', font =('Microsoft Sans Serif', 8))

def create_folder(): # Función para crear carpetas
    if editWidget.get():
        try:
            os.makedirs(editWidget.get()) # Crea carpeta
            messagebox.showinfo('Información', 'Se ha creado la carpeta en la ubicación seleccionada o predeterminada.', parent=root)
            os.startfile(editWidget.get()) # Abre la ubicación de la carpeta
            root.destroy()  
        except OSError as errorFolder:
            messagebox.showerror('Operación interrumpida',str(errorFolder), parent=root) # Excepciones o errores
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning('Crear carpeta', 'Debe especificar el nombre de la carpeta o la ubicación en donde se va a crear.', parent=root) 

btnOk = ttk.Button(root, text='Aceptar', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=create_folder, state='disabled')
btnOk.place(x=145,y=96) # Crea carpeta si hace clic en el botón

btnCancel = ttk.Button(root, text='Cancelar', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=root.destroy)
btnCancel.place(x=227,y=96)

def browseDialogFile():
    filenameBrowse = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(title='Seleccionar ubicación o destino', parent=root)
    
    editWidget.delete(0, tk.END)
    fileLocation = os.path.realpath(filenameBrowse)
    editWidget.insert(0, fileLocation) # Insertar texto mediante una cadena o String del cuadro de entrada


btnBrowse = ttk.Button(root, text='Examinar...', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=browseDialogFile)
btnBrowse.place(x=227,y=61) # Examinar o buscar ubicación

root.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos
```

Puede también crear subcarpetas a partir de una carpeta en el mismo cuadro de entrada.

> Tenga en cuenta que esto es ejemplo real de varios cuadros de diálogos que yo he hecho y he usado. El ejemplo está en una ventana principal, se puede utilizar como cuadro de diálogo también.